# Prepend the increment-ID(orderId) with the value(string) stored in magento 2.2

Tags: orders

How to write a code for to prepend increment-ID(orderId) number with the values(string) which is stored in magento2.2

Answer (score 1):

You can update the increment_prefix column in the store by your prefix value in `"eav_entity_store"` table